# Solang - panicked at 'type not allowed'

Tags: rust, ethereum, solidity, solana

I am trying to get an Ethereum smart contract up and running for Solana. I'm using **solang** and it had a few issues that I was able to fix, like Solidity's assembly not working, but I finally ran into something I can't handle.

I run [solang](https://solang.readthedocs.io/) build:
`solang ./lib/FastEcMul.sol --target solana --output build`
and I get:

```
thread 'main' panicked at 'type not allowed', src/sema/types.rs:920:18
```

more detailed, with `RUST_BACKTRACE=1` and `-v`:

```
info: Solang version v0.1.10
thread 'main' panicked at 'type not allowed', src/sema/types.rs:920:18
stack backtrace:
   0:        0x104833ce8 - <std::sys_common::backtrace::_print::DisplayBacktrace as core::fmt::Display>::fmt::h8483effd3e9ec544
   1:        0x10433e7e8 - core::fmt::write::ha34752bcd39bca36
   2:        0x1048327d0 - std::io::Write::write_fmt::hfc57a6e48a9ddae2
   3:        0x104832f98 - std::panicking::default_hook::{{closure}}::he9aaba83dd453f35
   4:        0x10483244c - std::panicking::rust_panic_with_hook::hf890018b6cf19ef5
   5:        0x10484f6e0 - std::panicking::begin_panic_handler::{{closure}}::hc0918e64b5d68f06
   6:        0x10484f668 - std::sys_common::backtrace::__rust_end_short_backtrace::hb99d925d54d4af60
   7:        0x10484f634 - _rust_begin_unwind
   8:        0x105b17e38 - core::panicking::panic_fmt::hf9e85df46ac02a7d
   9:        0x10449be1c - solang::sema::types::<impl solang::sema::ast::Type>::bits::h29f3c107ab9657a4
  10:        0x1045df378 - solang::sema::expression::bigint_to_expression::hc02ea43f3e21887f
  11:        0x1045f57bc - solang::sema::expression::power::ha1372353023ad777
  12:        0x1045e9078 - solang::sema::expression::expression::h07d54b6ce13d6489
  13:        0x1045f9ee0 - solang::sema::expression::subtract::hc24c7a4700f0e8e1
  14:        0x1045e8748 - solang::sema::expression::expression::h07d54b6ce13d6489
  15:        0x1045fba34 - solang::sema::expression::bitwise_and::hc24720f8c53e5be3
  16:        0x1045e8574 - solang::sema::expression::expression::h07d54b6ce13d6489
  17:        0x1045a22b4 - solang::sema::statements::destructure_values::h1d04cc668cdbf5fd
  18:        0x1045a13d0 - solang::sema::statements::destructure::h3937764899bb6c4d
  19:        0x104596968 - solang::sema::statements::statement::h392fdbc69b4da93d
  20:        0x10459568c - solang::sema::statements::statement::h392fdbc69b4da93d
  21:        0x104594868 - solang::sema::statements::resolve_function_body::hc7bc7aac8f20f106
  22:        0x10443518c - solang::sema::contracts::resolve::h4024bf7abc2ae716
  23:        0x10447a5e8 - solang::sema::sema_file::h3b89ac6a8acdaddb
  24:        0x10447c83c - solang::parse_and_resolve::hdc70bef828872f55
  25:        0x1047bb45c - solang::main::h5ce247c5504216e2
  26:        0x104799d24 - std::sys_common::backtrace::__rust_begin_short_backtrace::hb58d66c82bbbcc6f
  27:        0x1047b70a0 - _main
```

I got no idea, **which type is not allowed**, or where to find the file `src/sema/types.rs:920:18`.

However, I managed to compile other .sol file `EC.sol`, on which the FastEcMul.so is dependent. Yet the result was only `bundle.so` and `.abi` file is missing.

[link to both files](https://github.com/Hoshhi/BCVoting)

I'd be grateful for any clue.

Answer (score 0):

I've started looking at this issue. The first issue I can across was the doccomments which were not supported: https://github.com/hyperledger-labs/solang/pull/756

I'll continue looking at the next issue and get back.

Comment: I've fixed another issue in PR https://github.com/hyperledger-labs/solang/pull/759

Now the Solidity I have compiles fine. Please can you check with solang latest main branch.